# Javascript not loading in rails 7 - production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 7.1 app that works fine on localhost, but as soon as I ship it to production, the javascript doesn't load.

`app/views/application.html.erb`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= Rails.application.config.metadata["name"] %></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<%= Rails.application.config.metadata["description"] %>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= favicon_link_tag "favicon.ico" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "tailwind", "inter-font", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
  </head>
  <body class="min-w-full bg-white flex flex-col">
    <%= render "layouts/navigation" %>
    <main class="flex-grow">
      <%= yield %>
    </main>
    <%= render "layouts/modal" %>
  </body>
</html>
```

`app/javascript/application.js`

```js
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"

// Navbar menu
document.addEventListener("turbo:load", () => {
  var menu_button = document.getElementById("mobile-menu-button");
  var menu = document.getElementById("mobile-menu");
  if (menu_button) {
    menu_button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      menu.classList.toggle("hidden");
    });
  }
});
```

The only difference is I use a CDN.

`config/environments/production.rb`

```rb
...
config.asset_host = ENV.fetch("RAILS_ASSET_HOST") { nil }
...
```

I've also got multiple warnings:

```
[Warning] The resource https://cdn.multiplecurrenciesforynab.com/assets/turbo.min-dfd93b3092d1d0ff56557294538d069bdbb28977d3987cb39bc0dd892f32fc57.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it wasn't preloaded for nothing.
```

Comment: I don't see anything here that suggests the Javascript is not loading? Can you post whatever actual errors you might be receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Safari is not great at displaying the error: not allowed due to CORS policy. Had to use Chrome to get this.